# How to calculate player health percentage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have created the following objectives:

- health - health
- health1 - dummy (used for health*100)
- healthPerc - dumny (used for health1/20)

The only problem I'm having is that when I do: `/scoreboard players operation @p health1 *= 100 health`, it says `Set [health1] for Username to 0` (having 20/20 hearts)

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
R: /scoreboard players set @a temp 100
C: /scoreboard players operation @a health1 = @a health
C: /scoreboard players operation @p health1 *= @p temp
C: /scoreboard players set @a temp 20
C: /scoreboard players operation @p health1 /= @p temp
C: /scoreboard objectives setdisplay list health1
```

R>C>C>C>C>C

R=Repeating Command Block
C=Chain Command Block

This is the way I did it. To have a percentage of the health, I needed to calculate it since if the player has more than 20 hearts, then the output will be 100+%

Comment: This is a bit confusingly written and too complicated. For example you set "temp" to 100 for **every** player instead of just one dummy player. It also doesn't work with multiple players, because two of your commands only use "`@p`". And the maximum health can also be different than 20, with effects.

Comment: @FabianRöling My goal isn't to make it multiplayer friendly since it is supposed to be played in singleplayer and i want it to show 150% or 200% so I don't see the problem but thanks for lettim=ng me know anyways

Answer (score 7):

It's a but unfortunate, but Minecraft actually sees "100" as a valid username. Where you wrote it, you need a name, which can also be a dummy player. You need to assign that dummy player or entity the value 100 in some scoreboard and then you can use that for operations.

Comment: I found a way to do it. I'll put it here when i get home.

Comment: Something different than what I said? My solution is just two commands, I don't think you can do it in an easier way.

Comment: I posted my way of doing it as an answer. It isn't pretty, but it works